# How do I assign a ksh variable a value from remote environment variable?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, ksh, remote-server

Using a ksh script, I’m trying to get the value of an environment variable from a remote host and store it into a variable of my ksh script.
For example, on the remote host, the value $mypath is

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

So on my local host from my ksh, I was figuring I could do something like

```
ssh user@remotehost "echo $mypath”
```

But not sure what else to do after that if I want to assign it to a variable like myremotepath.

So far if I use this from my ksh script:

```
 ssh user@host 'ls -l'
 ssh user@host 'echo "HI"'
 ssh user@host 'echo $my_env_var'
```

The output is below. The ls and first echo command work, why wouldn't the 2nd echo work? I've verified my_env_var is defined on the remote host.

```
15:12:25 # ~/my.ksh 
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group1 40 Jul 15 15:06 myremote2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group1  1 Jul 15 13:28 myremote.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group1 22 Jun 29 15:29 tempR.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group1  3 Jun 29 16:11 temp.txt
HI
```

Comment: How are you verifying that the variable is set?

Comment: chepner, I logged into the remote host through another session and did an echo $my_env_var and it returned the expected value.

Comment: It would be informative if you could clarify whether or not there is a **blank line** output *after* `HI` and *before* your next prompt. This would indicate whether or not the `echo` command ever ran.

Comment: Are you sure you are using single quotes? `ssh user@host "echo $my_env_var"` would replace the `$my_env_var` with the local variable before calling ssh. Try `my_env_var=my_local_value` before calling ssh and see what you get.

Comment: Where is my_env_var set? Is it set by `.profile` ? Try `ssh user@host '. .profile; echo $my_env_var'`

Comment: We found out the issue. It had to do with the host serving two different environments.